# Nginx on kubernetes not serving static content

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have Nginx Open Source on AKS service. Every thing was good but unable to serve static content like index.html or favicon.ico.

When I open http:// it is not serving the index.html by default[i get 404] and if I try to open any static content I get 404 error.

nginx configuration was passed as ConfigMap and below is the config file that talks about serving static content.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
root /opt/abc/html; #also tried root /opt/abc/html/

location / {
root /opt/abc/html; #also tried root /opt/abc/html/
index index.html;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;

...
...
..

proxy_pass http://tomcat;
}
}
```

Setup:
Kubernetes on AKS
Nginx Open Source [no ingress]
configMaps to mount config.d
the static content (/opt/abc/html) was passed into pod with kubernetes cp command. [will this work?]

Comment: Please update/format your nginx config and provide kubernetes yaml.

Comment: when you log inside the pod (with `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -- /bin/bash`) do you see the static content there? Share the deployment so we can test and reproduce your issue!

Answer (score 0):

ref: https://github.com/RammusXu/toolkit/tree/master/k8s/echoserver

Here's a example to mount nginx.conf from ConfigMap

And make sure you `kubectl rollout restart deployment echoserver` after update ConfigMap. Pod only clone ConfigMap when it created. It don't sync or auto-updated.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echoserver
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echoserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echoserver
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-config

      containers:
      - name: echoserver
        # image: gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.10
        image: openresty/openresty:1.15.8.2-1-alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http

        # nginx.conf override
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          subPath: nginx.conf
          # mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          mountPath: /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
          readOnly: true
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echoserver
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: http
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: echoserver
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: default
data:
  nginx.conf: |-
    events {
      worker_connections 1024;
    }

    env HOSTNAME;
    env NODE_NAME;
    env POD_NAME;
    env POD_NAMESPACE;
    env POD_IP;

    http {
      default_type 'text/plain';
      # maximum allowed size of the client request body. By default this is 1m.
      # Request with bigger bodies nginx will return error code 413.
      # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size
      client_max_body_size 10m;

      # https://blog.percy.io/tuning-nginx-behind-google-cloud-platform-http-s-load-balancer-305982ddb340
      keepalive_timeout         650;
      keepalive_requests        10000;

      # GZIP support
      gzip                      on;
      gzip_min_length           128;
      gzip_proxied              any;
      gzip_comp_level           6;

      gzip_types                text/css
                                text/plain
                                text/javascript
                                application/javascript
                                application/json
                                application/x-javascript
                                application/xml
                                application/xml+rss
                                application/xhtml+xml
                                application/x-font-ttf
                                application/x-font-opentype
                                application/vnd.ms-fontobject
                                image/svg+xml
                                image/x-icon
                                application/rss+xml
                                application/atom_xml
                                application/vnd.apple.mpegURL
                                application/x-mpegurl
                                vnd.apple.mpegURL
                                application/dash+xml;

      init_by_lua_block {
        local template = require("template")
        -- template syntax documented here:
        -- https://github.com/bungle/lua-resty-template/blob/master/README.md
        tmpl = template.compile([[


    Hostname: {{os.getenv("HOSTNAME") or "N/A"}}

    Pod Information:
    {% if os.getenv("POD_NAME") then %}
      node name:    {{os.getenv("NODE_NAME") or "N/A"}}
      pod name: {{os.getenv("POD_NAME") or "N/A"}}
      pod namespace:    {{os.getenv("POD_NAMESPACE") or "N/A"}}
      pod IP:   {{os.getenv("POD_IP") or "N/A"}}
    {% else %}
      -no pod information available-
    {% end %}

    Server values:
      server_version=nginx: {{ngx.var.nginx_version}} - lua: {{ngx.config.ngx_lua_version}}

    Request Information:
      client_address={{ngx.var.remote_addr}}
      method={{ngx.req.get_method()}}
      real path={{ngx.var.request_uri}}
      query={{ngx.var.query_string or ""}}
      request_version={{ngx.req.http_version()}}
      request_scheme={{ngx.var.scheme}}
      request_uri={{ngx.var.scheme.."://"..ngx.var.host..":"..ngx.var.server_port..ngx.var.request_uri}}

    Request Headers:
    {% for i, key in ipairs(keys) do %}
      {{key}}={{headers[key]}}
    {% end %}

    Request Body:
    {{ngx.var.request_body or " -no body in request-"}}
    ]])
      }

      server {
        # please check the benefits of reuseport https://www.nginx.com/blog/socket-sharding-nginx-release-1-9-1
        # basically instructs to create an individual listening socket for each worker process (using the SO_REUSEPORT
        # socket option), allowing a kernel to distribute incoming connections between worker processes.
        listen 8080 default_server reuseport;
        listen 8443 default_server ssl http2 reuseport;

        ssl_certificate /certs/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /certs/privateKey.key;

        # Replace '_' with your hostname.
        server_name _;

        location / {
          lua_need_request_body on;
          content_by_lua_block {
            ngx.header["Server"] = "echoserver"

            local headers = ngx.req.get_headers()
            local keys = {}
            for key, val in pairs(headers) do
              table.insert(keys, key)
            end
            table.sort(keys)

            ngx.say(tmpl({os=os, ngx=ngx, keys=keys, headers=headers}))
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: i did this. every thing was working as expected but i was unable to mount and server static content files.

Comment: you need to provide your yamls.

Comment: i cant do that. its kind of huge file to me and cant pull from client system